# Automatically add link to pull request to JIRA

Tags: bitbucket, jira, pull-request

We have a setup with Bitbucket GIT linked to JIRA issue tracker. It is possible to add special comments to GIT commit messages to update JIRA issues automatically.

However, is it possible to put the link to the Pull Request, when it is created, to the corresponding JIRA issue? JIRA issue knows the name of the branch, so it should also have information on the pull requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference your issue keys in your commit messages, branches and pull requests then this information will automatically appear in your issue's development panel.

This requires that you have an application link configured between JIRA and Bitbucket.

This is how it should look:
[image]

More info is available on the [Development Information](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver074/viewing-the-development-information-for-an-issue-889531666.html) documentation page.